# KVM : domain names are resolved, but cannot ping

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, nat, ping

I've found that in KVM, my networking is acting funny.  Oddly

(1) I can resolve external internet locations using **nslookup** or **ping** , but I cannot actually receive a ping back.

(2) I cannot ping (even from my host) into my VM.  Nor can I ping my host from my VM.  So, networking is clearly, severely messed up.

[image: Resolved addresses, but cant ping them...]

However, my networking doesn't look particularly bad - eth0 seems to have a reasonable address etc...

[image]

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot a KVM box which is able to resolve, but not connect/ping, to a domain on the web ?  I've tested multiple domains (google,yahoo, etc...) and all seem to resolve no problem - indicating that the resolution process is not broken.

**UPDATE**

route -n output is shown below:

```
192.168.122.0    0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U   0 0 0 eth0
169.254.0.0      0.0.0.0  255.255.0.0   U   1002 0 0 eth0
0.0.0.0        192.168.122.1      UG  0 0 0 eth0
```

**UPDATE 2**

Actually, I cant even ping within my host into my VM, so something is definetly broke - and its not necessarily related to any external networking - its broken at the host->guest level.

Comment: Could you give us some details on your DNS configuration ? IP address ? And the result 'route -n' command too.

Comment: okay, ive done so above.

Comment: And whereis your DNS server ? On which network ? is there a firewall somewhere ? Your VM is natted or bridged on the host ?

Comment: The network settings are NAT.  I havent set up a DNS server.  this is a home computer - connecting to a simple home wireless airport extreme.